# verification of format of date being input, using java and selenium

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am not able to validate the format of a date being entered by the user using java and selenium.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(UserInput);
```

I think this will be used but not able to figure out how?
I want to check that date on a website is in MMMM dd format

Comment: why don't you use the dateFormat you just created to parse the input?

Comment: I have tried but it is having a problem ,it works fine for months with 4 letters like June and July but for others, I have to put as many M as there are letters in the spelling of that month .

Comment: And what if you take the amount of M's that exist in the name of the lonest month?

Comment: it is not about the M's in a month ,It is about the M's in a date format

Comment: That's what I mean... You say that "MMMM" matches "July" but won't match August. What if you take "MMMMMM" would that match both August and July?

Comment: Oh my bad !It will work only for august.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82933/discussion-between-rkstr22-and-cvesters).

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me:

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
final Date d = format.parse("August 27");
```